# the country code in the shipping address must match the buyer's country of residence

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, oscommerce

I am getting the above error during checkout through paypal services. I am using oscommerce account . I have throughly checked the shipping and billing address and they both are same. I really dont know why it is showing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i figured out so far is that shipping address while checking out from a website must match the address when you are logging in your paypal account for payment. If you are doing checkout from different country and your paypal address is in different country then it will show the above error.